# cforest prediction taking too long

Tags: random-forest, prediction, party

I am using the R-package `party` to build a random forest. The `cforest` function takes about 5 min to build a random forest model:

```
cf.model <- cforest(as.factor(y) ~ ., data = train.data, controls = cforest_control(ntree = 25, maxdepth = 6))
```

However, when I try to predict the training and test samples, the code sits there for hours, without giving me any output:

```
pTrain <- predict(cf.model, OOB = TRUE, type = "response")
pTest <- predict(cf.model, newdata = test.data, OOB = TRUE, type = "response")
```

Also tried the `type = "prob"` option without luck.

Would really appreciate any help with this. Does anyone else have the same problem? Should I be using different options to get the probability output.

I tried using `ctree` and that predicts just fine (and quite fast).

I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong here.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: FYI `ranger` is a fast RF package for R.

Comment: Please add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) for people to work with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.

Comment: Are you looking for adding a dataset to this example to make it reproducible?